# Porque mi server de AWS colapsa y no me permite entrar a mi sitio web, teniendo espacio en la instancia?

Tags: angularjs, aws

Tengo un problema con mi server de AWS, se que tiene espacio de sobra para el trafico de datos, pero aun asi los procesos se llenan y me hacer parar toda la aplicacion, porque sera?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: tendrás que ver en qué están ocupados esos procesos ...